# Process of going live of an Instagram App

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm just working on a Node.js project which uses Instagram API to boost up users likes/comments & follower numbers by focusing on user specific tags and automatically create organic bonds between users with liking and commenting. Or you can call this shortly as a Instagram bot.

However, the rate and user limits of the Instagram API made me curios about some stuff.

Firstly, the process for going live in Instagram looks so complex and toilsome so how the well-known Instagram BOTs (Archie, Instagress etc.) can made this ? Because I thought Instagram never accepted a usage for their API for this purpose and their Platform Policy is so strict that one can not hide their main purpose.

Secondly, even though app goes to live , the rate limit for endpoints used to publish (POST or DELETE) so limited that how these bots can work fluently without exceeding these limits even they have a lot of users ?

It would be best if anyone is experienced about Instagram API and the Instagram bots can answer there questions.

Answer (score 0):

they develop it without official instagram API, they used private API that uses instagram mobile application. I developed instagram bot, I have it on my local server.

Comment: How do you handle the API stuff ? Is this bot usable for public ?Or you just developed for your own ?

Comment: @OnurBurakYıldırım I just developed it for my own, but now I am developing service that will provide others to use it. it will be saas service